# Instantiating from an array in unity

Tags: c#, arrays, random, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I'm trying to instantiate a random asteroid gameobject that I've stored within an array. However I am getting an error with this and can't work it out. Can anyone help:

> Assets/Scripts/GameController.cs(7,49): error CS0236: A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property `GameController.asteroids'

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour {

    int asteroids = 2;     
    GameObject[] Asteroids = new GameObject[asteroids];

    public Vector3 spawnValues;
    public int asteroidCount;
    public float spawnWait;
    public float startWait;
    public float waveWait;

    void Start () {

        //call asteroid array variables
        Asteroids [0] = gameObject.tag == "Asteroid01";
        Asteroids [1] = gameObject.tag == "Asteroid02";

        StartCoroutine (spawnWaves ());
    }

    IEnumerator spawnWaves () {

        yield return new WaitForSeconds (startWait);

        while (true) {
            for (int i = 0; i < asteroidCount; i++) {
                Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3 (spawnValues.x, Random.Range (-spawnValues.y, spawnValues.y), spawnValues.z);
                Quaternion spawnRotation = Quaternion.identity;

                Instantiate (Random.Range(0,1), spawnPosition, spawnRotation);
                yield return new WaitForSeconds (spawnWait);
            }
        }
    }
```

edit:

I've been playing with this and this is what I have so far:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject[] asteroids;
    public Vector3 spawnValues;
    public int asteroidCount;
    public float spawnWait;
    public float startWait;
    public float waveWait;

    void Start () {
        asteroids = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Asteroid");
        StartCoroutine (spawnWaves ());
    }

    IEnumerator spawnWaves () {

        while (true) {
            for (int i = 0; i < asteroidCount; i++) {
                Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3 (spawnValues.x, Random.Range (-spawnValues.y, spawnValues.y), spawnValues.z);
                Quaternion spawnRotation = Quaternion.identity;
                Instantiate (asteroids[i], spawnPosition, spawnRotation);
                yield return new WaitForSeconds (spawnWait);
            }
        }
```

Comment: `int asteroids = 2;` needs to be `static` or `const`, or you need to move `Asteroids = new GameObject[asteroids];` inside the constructor (or `Start()`);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not the correct way of instantiating game objects. Instead, try this one:

```
Instantiate (Asteroids[i], spawnPosition, spawnRotation);
```

The error is that the first parameter is a game object, but in your code you pass a float value. Also move your `new GameObject[asteroids]` code inside the contructor or to the `Start()` method, or try using a constant/static int value instead.

Comment: I've updated this. I didn't realise I hadn't stated the array in the instantiate command! However, this still doesn't seem to work. My game doesn't freeze on play now which is a good start I guess but it doesn't instantiate anything. Any ideas? I've reposted the updated code in the original post :)

Comment: Are you sure instantiate got called? Because asteroidCount is not set so I assume it got 0 value.

Comment: i got this working. asteroidCount is public and declared in the component editor. The issue seemed to be that i wasn't loading the array correctly. I also ended up putting the prefabs in the array manually, instead of via the game object tags

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use one instance variable to initialize another instance variable, because the compiler can't guarantee the order of initialization.

You can do it in the constructor:

```
public class GameController : MonoBehaviour {

    int asteroids;     
    GameObject[] Asteroids;

    public GameController()
    {
        asteroids = 2;
        Asteroids = new GameObject[asteroids]
    }
...
```

Or as cubrr said in the comment asteroids can be a constant.

Comment: "because the compiler can't guarantee the order of initialization." That's not true: you can't use one instance variable to initialize another because you can't use `this`, but ["variable initializers are executed in the textual order in which they appear in the class declaration."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645759%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot initialize array with normal variable in that manner.
Either you can do

```
const int asteroids = 2;     
GameObject[] Asteroids = new GameObject[asteroids];
```

or

```
int asteroids = 2;     
GameObject[] Asteroids;

void Start()
{
 Asteroids = new GameObject[asteroids];
}
```